# How to clear part of the buffer?

Tags: c, buffer

I'm editing the post because people said its unclear what I want.

I work a code and I need an idea on how to clear only part of the buffer.

for example, if this data exist in the buffer: `)) 1 ((a>)` I need to clean it until I see `space` (including the space).

Comment: I can easily put that program in an infinite loop, by pressing the `EOF` key. You need to include an `EOF` check, and for that to work properly you need to remember that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an **`int`**.

Comment: As for your problem, please explain your code to your [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Especially that lone`getchar()` call before the loop. What does it do?

Comment: You ignore the first character read by `getchar()`; you ignore the possibility of EOF from the second one; you don't store the return value of `getchar()` into an `int` as required for reliable operation.  Those are all serious flaws. We can discuss whether you need a newline in the output another time.  Suffice to say that on many systems, you won't see any output from the `printf()` operations until you output a newline or fill the output buffer (which can be 512 to 4096 bytes long, depending on the system).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I wanted to enter the buffer this ` 1 ((a>)` becouse its a case in my code that I want to fix.

Comment: If you want to read more than one character, you should consider a string input function.  You don't say whether the `1 ((a>)` is part of a longer line or on a line on its own.  You don't seem to be saving any of the input, or verifying that it matches what you say you want to match.  We need more information — an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler maybe if I explain it like this it will help:  I have some data in the buffer, and I need to delete all of it until I see the number `1`, (not to delete it). (I'm not allowed to use strings)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried to clarify myself in the comment below.

Comment: You refer to 'buffer' — is that a character array in memory, or are you referring to the input buffer behind a file stream?  And is that file stream `stdin`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler to be honest I'm not sure :\. I'm new, just started to learn. but when I say buffer I mean the place that the input goes to. (hope its make sense)

Comment: The code you showed originally was *almost* correct, but it lacked one thing: Assigning the result of the very first `getchar()` to your `bufferCheck` variable. Which is what I tried to make you realize with my previous comments.

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use arrays?  Some asinine teacher holding a pistol to your head (or your grades)?  What is the real task?  This is sounding like an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  ……Thanks for accepting my answer — I'm glad it helped, but you could make it easier for us to help you by explaining what you're up to more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read from standard input (`stdin`) up to the next space, then you can use:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != ' ')
    ;
if (c == EOF)
    …time to bail out…
```

The loop looks for the end marker (`EOF`) or the character you're after.  You need to decide whether newline `\n` should also be handled.

If you have the data in a string, `char *buffer = …`, then you do something somewhat similar:

```
char *buffer = …;
char *ptr = buffer;
while (*ptr != '\0' && *ptr != ' ')
    ptr++;
if (*ptr == '\0')
    …time to bail out…
```

Again, the loop looks for the end marker (`'\0'` for a string instead of `EOF` for a file) or the desired character.  If the loop exits, `ptr` points to the space that ended it.  You may need to skip further spaces, etc.  You might have to deal with a space at the end of the string (where `ptr[1] == '\0'`).